# Which batches are used during training when `limit_train_batches = n` in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I have a question about the behavior of `limit_train_batches` in the Trainer class when using PyTorch Lightning and would be grateful for your help.

I am trying to train some Unet-like models to denoise my data. My training dataset however, is very large and it takes me a lot of time to train all these models. In order to speed things up, I would like to limit the number of samples that the model is trained on during an epoch. So for instance, if my entire training dataset were composed of 1000 samples and I were using a batch size of 50, it would need to make 20 passes over my training data to have "seen" all of it. Due to time constraints, I would like to limit the samples to 200. Assuming that I were still using a batch size of 50, I would now only need to make 4 passes over the training data for my model to have seen all 200 samples in a certain epoch. Instead of creating a single subset of 200 samples from my original dataset, I would like to ensure that the model sees a different subset of 200 samples during each epoch to ensure that there is enough variability in the training data.

If I set the `limit_train_batch = 4`, would the Trainer class end up using the first 4 batches that the dataloader creates?

Here is a small example to illustrate what I mean.

Say my training data is composed of of 20 random numbers ranging from 0-10

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

toy_training_data = [6 3 7 4 6 9 2 6 7 4 3 7 7 2 5 4 1 7 5 1]
dataloader = DataLoader(toy_training_data, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

for epoch in range(2):
    for batch in dataloader:
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, batch: {batch}")
    print("End of epoch", epoch)
```

The output of the dataloader when I shuffle the data after each epoch is as follows:

```
Epoch: 0, batch: tensor([7, 5, 7, 1])
Epoch: 0, batch: tensor([3, 4, 5, 4])
Epoch: 0, batch: tensor([4, 7, 6, 6])
Epoch: 0, batch: tensor([3, 6, 2, 1])
Epoch: 0, batch: tensor([7, 2, 7, 9])
End of epoch 0
Epoch: 1, batch: tensor([5, 7, 2, 7])
Epoch: 1, batch: tensor([4, 6, 6, 5])
Epoch: 1, batch: tensor([4, 4, 6, 7])
Epoch: 1, batch: tensor([7, 7, 1, 2])
Epoch: 1, batch: tensor([3, 1, 3, 9])
End of epoch 1
```

If I were to set `limit_train_batches = 2`, would I expect that it only uses the first 2 batches in every epoch so `batch: tensor([7, 5, 7, 1], batch: tensor([3, 4, 5, 4]` for epoch 0 and then `batch: tensor([5, 7, 2, 7], batch: tensor([4, 6, 6, 5]` for epoch 1 and so on.

Assuming this is indeed the behavior of the `limit_train_batches`, would you say that this is a good strategy to ensure variability in training data while still keeping the training time in check. If not, I would also love to hear your guys' opinion on how I could solve this problem more efficiently.

Thank you so much for taking the time to read through my post, and I look forward to hearing your answers!